# How to encrypt with an EC-generated public key?

Tags: java, spring-boot, bouncycastle

This is my testfunction to have a look at BouncyCastles use of
key-generation, sign/verify and asymmetrical encrypt/decrypt.

```
public void foo (String prov, String keyalgo, String signalgo, String encralgo) throws Exception
{
    // init boundycastle
    Security.addProvider (new BouncyCastleProvider ());
    
    // generate keypair
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance (keyalgo, prov);
    if (keyalgo.equals("RSA"))
    {
        kpg.initialize (2048);
    }
    else if (keyalgo.equals ("EC"))
    {
        kpg.initialize (new ECGenParameterSpec ("brainpoolP384r1"));
    }
    KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair ();
    
    // sign
    Signature s = Signature.getInstance (signalgo, prov);
    s.initSign (kp.getPrivate ());
    
    String data = "heyheyhey";
    s.update (data.getBytes());
    byte sv [] = s.sign ();

    // verify
    s.initVerify (kp.getPublic ());
    s.update (data.getBytes());
    System.out.println ("verify: " + s.verify (sv));
    
    // encrypt
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance (encralgo, prov);
    c.init (Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, kp.getPublic ());
    byte encr [] = c.doFinal (data.getBytes ());
    
    // decrypt
    c.init (Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, kp.getPrivate ());                     
    byte decr [] = c.doFinal (encr);
    System.out.println ("decrypt: " + new String (decr).equals (data));
}
```

This works fine if I use this parameters for simple RSA.

```
foo ("BC", "RSA", "SHA256withRSA", "RSA/ECB/OAEPwithSHA1andMGF1Padding");
```

But I do not get it going if I use an EC-key. Sign/verify is ok with different algo-name, but what to set for encrypt/decrypt??

```
foo ("BC", "ECDSA", "SHA256withECDSA", "RSA/ECB/OAEPwithSHA1andMGF1Padding");
```

Fails at line

```
c.init (Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, kp.getPublic ());
```

with

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: unknown key type passed to RSA
```

Comment: You cannot encrypt/decrypt with EC as you can with RSA (although there is ElGamal for EC, this is usually not applied in practice). With EC, ECDH is used, i.e. both sides generate a shared secret, from which usually a key for symmetric encryption (e.g. for AES) is derived.

Comment: Thats exactly my usecase. I used RSA for securely transmitting a symmetric algo secret. Now I need to change the keypair from RSA to EC-brainpool. So I will have a look at ECDH.

Comment: @Topaco+ BouncyCastle (in Java) implements several instances of the ECIES scheme, which does the whole job for you: ECDH(E-S) + symmetric encryption (DESede or AES) + HMAC. Entering "bouncycastle java ecies" in the search box above gets 18 hits and at a quick skim it looks like about half of them directly address this Q.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085+ This is a good addition in light of the client's last comment that they are *actually* looking for a hybrid EC encryption method (the original question seemed to me to be more about a comparison between RSA and EC). With regard to ECIES, however, one disadvantage should also be pointed out, namely that there is not just one standard, but several, which are generally not compatible with each other. This is particularly important when different platforms and libraries come into play. But if this is not a problem, then ECIES is convenient because it does the whole job.